# Responsive Contact form

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, contact-form

I'm looking to reproduce something like the responsive contact form on this [site](http://forefathersgroup.com/) with the trigger to open and close the form being the ribbon below, and was hoping someone could give me some tips on how it is done with jquery. I'm not really sure where to begin in terms of positioning the open/close button, and getting the form to work.

Would I be right in saying this is an accordion with form elements inside?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why I have being marked down for this question? Happy to rephrase.

Comment: Likely because you have asked for something without demonstrating what you have actually tried. Try something then come back with specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article and demo that has similar function to what you are looking for.
http://www.zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts